# How can I call my own custom SQL code inside my Java EE project on NetBeans

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, netbeans

How do I create a custom SQL command and override the automatic handling in the netBeans project?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What "automatic handling" are you talking about?

Comment: So my Netbeans project uses something called EntityManager and we'd like to bypass it (http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html )

Answer (score 1):

The `EntityManager` is part of the Java Persistence API (JPA). You're either setting it up yourself or your server (persumably Glassfish inside NetBeans?) is setting it up for you.

Here's a quick example of what you can do:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select name from people");
List<String> results = query.getResultList();
```

[This is a more complete example.](http://developerhelpway.com/framework/jpahibernate/jpa-native-query.php)